# Using large files in the backend

Tags: machine-learning, flask, deployment, backend, yolov4

I made an object detection website using Flask framework in the backend and am using yolov3.weights(240mb) file as a pre-trained model. I was just wondering what is the correct way of hosting these type of websites with large files such as yolov3 running in the backend

Don't have any idea how to solve this just looking for the right way